# jQuery Autocomplete view description

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to include a description in my autocomplete input. Im a rookie but im sure there is only something little missing or something little to be changed.
My code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ydkg1r2/2/

```
(function($){
var $project = $('#name');
var projects = [
{
  value: "Example 1",
  label: "Example 1",
  desc: "Example Description 1",
  icon: "1.jpg"
},
{
  value: "Example 2",
  label: "Example 2",
  desc: "Example Description 2",
  icon: "2.jpg"
},
];

$project.autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
matchCase : true,
source: projects,
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  $project.val( ui.item.label );
  return false;
}
 });

$project.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

var $li = $('<li>'),
    $img = $('<img>');

$img.attr({
  src: 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/' + item.icon,
  alt: item.label
});

$li.attr('data-value', item.label);
$li.append('<a href="#">');
$li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);    

return $li.appendTo(ul);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your item description too.
So replace this :

```
$li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);
```

By this :

```
$li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label).append(item.desc);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any easy way u can style those 2 lines of text and put it under each other?

Comment: Yes you can append these two lines of text in divs then add some css style to these divs. `$li.find('a').append($img).append('<div class="item-title">'+ item.label +'</div>').append('<div class="item-desc">'+ item.desc +'</div>');`